# How to solve order total and invoice total mismatch?

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, invoice, grand-total

I am using this [extension](https://github.com/yvoronoy/magento-extension-extra-fee) for adding extra fees,

In checkout page,

[image]

Order total before creating invoice,

[image]

After creating invoice,

[image]

Error :  The invoice total and order total not matching in invoice,

[image]

Customer feel order total & invoice total different, How to manage this case?

**FYI** - If i try with fresh magento, extra fees showing on order total in order page and invoice & order also same total.

Comment: I had the same problem, had to hire a developer to fix it, that extension is incomplete and has other problems

Answer (score 0):

in the config.xml file you need to add the below code in  tag

```
<adminhtml>
                <rewrite>
                    <sales_totals>Voronoy_ExtraFee_Block_Adminhtml_Sales_Totals</sales_totals>
                    <sales_order_totals>Voronoy_ExtraFee_Block_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_Totals</sales_order_totals>
                    <sales_order_invoice_totals>Voronoy_ExtraFee_Block_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_Invoice_Totals</sales_order_invoice_totals>
                </rewrite>
            </adminhtml>
```

create new file Totals.php at Voronoy/ExtraFee/Block/Adminhtml/Sales folder

```
<?php

class Voronoy_ExtraFee_Block_Adminhtml_Sales_Totals extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Totals
{
    protected function _initTotals()
    {
        parent::_initTotals();
        $source = $this->getSource();

        $totals = $this->_totals;
        $total = array();
        if (count($totals) > 0) {
            foreach ($totals as $index => $val) {
                if ($index == "grand_total") {
                    if (((float)$this->getSource()->getExtraFeeRuleAmount()) != 0) {
                        $label = $this->__('Extra Fee');
                        $total['extra_fee_rule_amount'] = new Varien_Object(array(
                            'code' => 'extra_fee_rule_amount',
                            'field' => 'extra_fee_rule_amount',
                            'value' => $source->getExtraFeeRuleAmount(),
                            'label' => $label
                        ));
                    }


                }
                $total[$index] = $val;
            }
            $this->_totals = $total;
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

create file Totals.php at  Voronoy/ExtraFee/Block/Adminhtml/Sales/Order/

```
<?php

class Voronoy_ExtraFee_Block_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_Totals extends Voronoy_ExtraFee_Block_Adminhtml_Sales_Totals
{
    protected function _initTotals()
    {
        parent::_initTotals();
        $this->_totals['paid'] = new Varien_Object(array(
            'code' => 'paid',
            'strong' => true,
            'value' => $this->getSource()->getTotalPaid(),
            'base_value' => $this->getSource()->getBaseTotalPaid(),
            'label' => $this->helper('sales')->__('Total Paid'),
            'area' => 'footer'
        ));
        $this->_totals['refunded'] = new Varien_Object(array(
            'code' => 'refunded',
            'strong' => true,
            'value' => $this->getSource()->getTotalRefunded(),
            'base_value' => $this->getSource()->getBaseTotalRefunded(),
            'label' => $this->helper('sales')->__('Total Refunded'),
            'area' => 'footer'
        ));
        $this->_totals['due'] = new Varien_Object(array(
            'code' => 'due',
            'strong' => true,
            'value' => $this->getSource()->getTotalDue(),
            'base_value' => $this->getSource()->getBaseTotalDue(),
            'label' => $this->helper('sales')->__('Total Due'),
            'area' => 'footer'
        ));
        return $this;
    }
}
```

create file Totals at Voronoy/ExtraFee/Block/Adminhtml/Sales/Order/Invoice/ folder

```
<?php

class Voronoy_ExtraFee_Block_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_Invoice_Totals extends Voronoy_ExtraFee_Block_Adminhtml_Sales_Totals
{
    protected $_invoice = null;

    public function getSource()
    {
        return $this->getInvoice();
    }

    public function getInvoice()
    {
        if ($this->_invoice === null) {
            if ($this->hasData('invoice')) {
                $this->_invoice = $this->_getData('invoice');
            } elseif (Mage::registry('current_invoice')) {
                $this->_invoice = Mage::registry('current_invoice');
            } elseif ($this->getParentBlock()->getInvoice()) {
                $this->_invoice = $this->getParentBlock()->getInvoice();
            }
        }
        return $this->_invoice;
    }

    protected function _initTotals()
    {
        parent::_initTotals();
        $total = 0;


        $this->_totals['grand_total'] = new Varien_Object(array(
            'code' => 'grand_total',
            'strong' => true,
            'value' => ($this->getSource()->getGrandTotal() + $total),
            'base_value' => ($this->getSource()->getBaseGrandTotal() + $total),
            'label' => $this->helper('sales')->__('Grand Total'),
            'area' => 'footer'
        ));
        return $this;
    }
}
```

Comment: I just try with fresh magento its working, may i know how to find my error and solve it instead of doing changes in files?

Comment: in that extension if you want to add extra fee line than you need to override total block

Comment: But my fresh magento showing extra fees in my order total without override any block.

Comment: How to debug my case?

Comment: which magento version are you using?

Comment: Make me pardon for late reply, My version : 1.9.2.3 @ Jigs Parmar